# Does Room support entity inheritance?

Tags: android-room

I am trying to migrate our project to use Room, which, by the way, I think is an awesome step forward.

I have the following structure:

```
public class Entity extends BaseObservable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER) 
    private long mId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_dirty")
    @TypeConverters(BooleanTypeConverter.class)
    private boolean mIsDirty;

    // default constructor and accessors omitted for brevity
}

@Entity(tableName = "some_entities")
public class SomeEntity extends Entity {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)        
    private String mType;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
    private long mTimestamp;

    // constructor, accessors
}
```

When I try to compile my project, it fails with no specific error.

If I try to compile it with a flat entity hierarchy, all is well.

So, my main question is:
Does Room support entity inheritance? Will it be able to get the column definitions from the parent `Entity` class?

I would also like to know if extending `BaseObservable` (which I need to get the Data Binding working) can cause problems with Room? `BaseObservable` has one private transient field, so maybe this is causing some issues with the code generation.

Are there any recommended patterns to deal with this, or will I just have to flatten my entity hierarchy?

Comment: So, I did a bit more testing and turns out that: YES, Room does support inheritance and YES, extending `BaseObservable` is a problem. I am currently removing the `BaseObservable` from the entity hierarchy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After further investigation it turns out that Room Entities should not extend the `BaseObservable` class. It contains fields that can't be marked with `@Ignore` and break the code generation.

Room works well with inheritance. The annotations are processed as expected and the DB operations behave normally. You can extend from both an Entity and a POJO.

Comment: Does room support TypeConverters to be put on open class in kotlin? By any chance if you are aware

Comment: Can you provide some example code snippets, how did you the setup to inherit an entity and query the extended entity from the db?

Comment: I am having issues extending objects, because the Dao validation uses the parent class instead of the child extended classes.

Comment: @DeaMon1, have you passed tableName value to Entity annotation to parent or child or both?

Comment: Does this mean if you have your base class `Entity` and two classes that inherit from it, Room will be able to query an object using the BaseClass attributes (e.g. `id`) and then create the ChildClass entity of the correct type?

Comment: @lucidbrot Yes. You can create a query that returns the child type and access the properties of the base class in the query clauses.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev can I annotate the ParentClass as `@Entity(tableName="mytable")`  or do I need a separate table for each ChildClass? I cannot get the first option to  work (yet)

Comment: @lucidbrot No, you shouldn't annotate the parent class with `@Entity`. If you're still trying to get this to work and have posted another question, I'll be more than happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, @DanailAlexiev ! I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56142162/2550406) - I have a solution that kinda works, but it feels like there must be a better/cleaner/easier way